# Gradle Zip: retain the directory structures

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

I'm creating the Zip of my java files as below but it doesn't retain the directory structure in the `.zip`

```
task ('apiJavaDocSources', type: Zip) {

    from fileTree('core-module/src/mypackage/').matching {
        'subpackage/*Exception.java'
        'subpackage/package-info.java'
        'anotherpackage/*.java'
    }

    from fileTree('lib-module/src/mypackage/').matching {
        'bundleinfo/*Dummy.java'
        'bundleinfo/Random.java'
    }
    archiveName 'api-javadoc-sources.zip'
    destinationDir(file('image'))
}
```

I want to retain the directory structure in zip as

```
  api-javadoc-sources.zip
   -- core-module
      -- /src/mypackage/
        -- subpackage/*.java
        -- anotherpackage/*.java
   -- lib-module
      -- /src/mypackage/
        -- bundleinfo/*.java
```

But, My implementation just putting all `*.java` in root of `.zip` , how can I retain the directory structure here inside zip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fileTree()` method will not preserve the directory hierarchy you are sourcing from. You need to specify the `into` directory in your copy specifications to specify that you want the matched files to be placed in a directory inside of the zip.

The following task should accomplish what you want:

```
task ('apiJavaDocSources', type: Zip) {
    // search for files in this directory
    from('core-module/src/mypackage') {
        // indicates that all matches files should be nested in this directory inside of the zip
        into 'core-module/src/mypackage'
        // match file patterns
        include 'subpackage/*Exception.java'
        include 'subpackage/package-info.java'
        include 'anotherpackage/*.java'
    }

    from('lib-module/src/mypackage') {
        into 'lib-module/src/mypackage'
        include 'bundleinfo/*Dummy.java'
        include 'bundleinfo/Random.java'
    }
    
    archiveName 'api-javadoc-sources.zip'
    destinationDir(file('image'))
}
```